# Changing Nuxt assets url in generated HTML files

Tags: javascript, vue.js, frontend, nuxt.js, static-site-generation

I'm trying to generate a static website with nuxt but I need it to work without a server, just opening the html files with a browser. One of the problems are the urls of the assets imported in the html files because I need the url to be

```
src="_nuxt/..."
```

instead of

```
src="/_nuxt/..."
```

is it possible to change this config?

Comment: To my knowledge, you cannot have an SSG server without a free server running. Even a free one like on Netlify. You need to have a build tool running it. What is such use case of avoiding that? Modern apps don't work from a simple `.html` nowadays.

Answer (score 0, accepted):

AFAIK, there is no way to do this with nuxt. Because you're trying to change absolute paths to relatives, which is not really the way it's intented to work.

But a simple solution is to use `npx serve` to run a local http server to serve your static files easily:

```bash
$ npx serve

   ┌─────────────────────────────────────────┐
   │                                         │
   │   Serving!                              │
   │                                         │
   │   - Local:    http://localhost:3000     │
   │   - Network:  http://XX:XX:XX:XX:3000   │
   │                                         │
   │   Copied local address to clipboard!    │
   │                                         │
   └─────────────────────────────────────────┘
```

Just go to this address and you'll see the files in the folder you executed the command :)

Comment: Even if the files are fixed, there will be more issues anyway.